# Bug in Snowflake datetime formatting?

Tags: datetime, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After `alter session set TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MITZH:TZM';`
I execute `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` and get:

```
+-----------------------+                                                       
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     |
|-----------------------|
| 2022-02-17T08:30-0800 |
+-----------------------+
```

Notice there is no ":" between the TZH and the TZM: 0800 instead of 08:00. For this same timestamp format, the docs have, as an example, `2013-04-28T20:57+07:00` --- with the ":". Looks like a bug --- or am I missing something?

(Using snowsql on MacOs)

Answer (score 0):

Using Classic UI/Snowsight the `:` is visible:

```
alter session set TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MITZH:TZM';

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_VERSION();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like OP is using SnowSQL CLI, where oddly enough, what he is seeing is correct

Comment: That's right, using the SnowSQL CLI. Seems to be an artifact of that ---when I export the data, the ":" shows up. The CLI vs. web console seem to be treating the quotes around "T" differently, too.

Comment: @PhilCoulson by "seeing is correct" do you mean "it is experienced as reported" aka it is a bug in the SnowSQL CLI. It also renders as wanted ~correctly~ in the new UI `2022-02-17"T"16:34-08:00`, `6.4.1`

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Yes, the issue can be reproduced in SnowSQL but works as expected in the new and old web UI